# Change date format to echo days only without 0

Tags: php, date

I have

```
$date= '2013-11-03';
```

I need to edit this format to echo days only and without 0 too

so the output = 3

How i can do that please ?

Comment: Please use google. Try something before you post here. Hint: You can use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `d` character will return the day value padded with a leading zero, by printing the value with `printf()` and using `%d` as the placeholder, the string value will be converted to an integer which therefore strips away the leading zero.

```
$date = '2013-11-03';
$dateSet =  date('d', strtotime($date));
printf("%d", $dateSet);
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
$dt_str = '2013-11-03';
$date   = new Datetime($dt_str);
echo $date->format('Y-m-j');
```

If you need only day to be displayed :

```
echo $date->format('j');
```